# Is there a Rhinomock version of AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization?

Tags: rhino-mocks, autofixture

I am bound to use Rhinomocks in my current project. Is there a way of setting up using Autofixture with Rhinomocks to achieve the same behaviour as when combining AutoFixture with Moq using the AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization customization?

Currently I have to do a lot of dummy mock setups in my test code as seen below. In the code i dont really care about the locations that I create. I just want the GetAllLocations method to return a random list of locations instead of null:

```
var f = new Fixture();
        var masterDataProvider = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IMasterDataProvider>();
        masterDataProvider.Stub(x => x.GetAllLocations()).Return(f.CreateMany<Location>());
        f.Inject(masterDataProvider);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The various Glue Libraries for AutoFixture don't have full feature parity. `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization` is one of the features that are only partially ported to other Glue Libraries. IIRC, it's only available for Moq and one other dynamic mock library.

So the short answer is that *no*, this feature isn't available for Rhino Mocks.

---

*Original answer:*

Yes, you can use [AutoFixture.AutoRhinoMocks](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoRhinoMocks) instead of [AutoFixture.AutoMoq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.AutoMoq). It works the same way, but some of the type names are different - for example, the `ICustomization` you should use is called `AutoRhinoMockCustomization`.

Comment: I did try AutoRhinoMocks, but I cannot get it to work in the way I want. In the above example, if I use the AutoRhinoMockCustomization the returned value of GetAllLocations() is null. Is there a way of having it return a default value of, say 3 items, just like when calling f.CreateMany()? I am not looking for a specific solution to solve just this case, but for a generic one. With Moq I think this is possible, but I am unsure of RhinoMocks.

Comment: @Flodpanter Sorry, I misunderstood the question. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for stating that :-) I was not a big fan of Rhinomocks and this just adds to that.